# scikit - RandomForestClassifier query

Tags: scikit-learn

I am having problem to understand if these 2 steps using scikit are similar:

1) RandomForestClassifier with compute_importance=True , and manually selecting top 10 features as returned to further create new training set of 10 features and train and further predict.

2)  RandomforestClassifier with max_feature=10 compute_importance=True and further using rf.fit_transform(train,target) and further rf.fit(train,target)

Comment: Do you mean feature_importances_ ?
If so, Daniel Mahlers's answer is clear and so the answer to you question is no.

Answer (score 0):

`max_features=10` means that a new random subset of 10 features is selected from the overall set as candidates for splitting on. In other words different 10 features are being considered every time. All of the original features may still end up being used somewhere in the same tree and thus also in the whole forest. Selecting the 10 most important features and retraining means that the same 10 feature are used everywhere, which is usually not a good idea.